# Why we need javax.persistence.EntityManager.detach() if we have session.evict()?

Tags: hibernate, session

also what does `javax.persistence.EntityManager.remove()` method does different than above two methods ?

What is the difference between session.evict() ,

javax.persistence.EntityManager.detach() and

javax.persistence.EntityManager.remove() , session.delete() ?

Comment: didnt downvote, but you probably got downvoted because they are different method that you can read very easily on the javadoc so the question seems like a lack of effort on your par...

Comment: I knew about evict but couldn't find anything on detach method, that's why I got confused and mentioned all three methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those three are method used for very different things.

1. `remove()` mark the persisted entity for removal, meaning that at
   flush time hibernate will generate the corresponding `sql` delete
   statement.
2. `evict()` is for removing an entity from the internal cache
   (hibernate first level cache). If you load an entity from `db` hibernate will store it in the cache and subsequent query will hit the cache first. Evicting the entity force hibernate to query `db` again.
3. `detach()` is used when you want to make an entity unmanaged. You basically
   tell hibernate to stop tracking that entity modification (dirty checking) so that if you update it's field in any way you won't have those changes reflected on `db`.

Comment: If remove() will generate delete query, then what will delete()  generate?
I know delete() also removes record from database.

Comment: @Ninad Gosavi they are the same, only remove is a jpa EntityManager method while delete is hibernate Session

Comment: I just found out that detach(), remove() methods  are from javax.persistence.EntityManager where as evict() ,delete() methods are from org.hibernate.Session. and detach() is also removing object from session as evict() does.

Comment: It is still unclear to me, evict actually removes the cache but still removes the entity and not managed anymore by the session?